# How do I debug a memory leakage issue in Zope?

Tags: python, memory-leaks, zope

Our web application is hogging memory when the load is high. We don't see any
patterns that implicate any particular URL. Hence it looks like we would need to dig a bit more and see whats really happening with requests vis-a-vis memory. Are there any memory profilers that can monitor per URL memory consumption in the server?

If I could assume that once the request is processed, the incremental memory is a leakage, I was thinking of monitoring the process memory at the Zope's Request(where the request hits first) and Publish(where it servers the content finally) classes and compare the difference. However since `Zope` seems to support `threading` which is a new concept to me, will there be there be a scenario where Thread1 Request starts processing, we capture the memory of the process at that time, Thread2 Request stars and finishes with some memory lekage, T1 finishes and we capture the memory causing T1 to show up memory leak of T2 as well since its the same process? Isn't that a general problems with thread and memory monitoring?

How do I debug this problem? Even if its from a different framework I would like to hear that.

Comment: What Zope version are you using? Can it be ZODB cache? Delayed garbage collection? Are you using ZEO and/or any reverse proxy?

Comment: @mlt Zope2-2.13.22. We use ZeO and also Apache for load balancing. Its running on Windows as well. How do I check delayed garbage collection? Is there a way to gc forcefully?

Comment: `gc.collect()`?. Perhaps you may find [this old post](http://maurits.vanrees.org/weblog/archive/2007/10/how-to-minimize-cpu-and-memory-usage-of-zope-and-plone-applications) helpful.